# jqGrid with inlineNav: how to get Id after savefunctionn

Tags: jqgrid

I am use inline nav in Jqgrid. 
I am validating the grid through database when data is valid  my line is save. but when data is not valid i want to keep grid in edit mode so please give me suggestion.

@Oleg

```
jQuery("#voucherGrid").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager", {
        addParams: {
            useDefValues: true,
            addRowParams: {
                keys: true,
                extraparam: { 
                    Voucher_Type: function(){                                   
                        return $('#vaoucherTypeSel').val();
                    }
                },
                successfunc : function(response,id){
                    $('.modal-body').text(response.responseText);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');

                    if(response.responseText.length < 8){

                    }else{
                        var myGrid = $('#voucherGrid');
                        selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        myGrid.jqGrid('editRow',selRowId);
                        $('#voucherGrid_ilsave').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $('#voucherGrid_ilcancel').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $('#voucherGrid_iladd').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        editParams : {
             keys: true,
            extraparam : {
                Voucher_Type : function(){                                  
                    return $('#vaoucherTypeSel').val();
                }
            },
            successfunc : function(response){
                $('.modal-body').text(response.responseText);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                if(response.responseText.length < 8){

                }else{          
                    var myGrid = $('#voucherGrid');
                    selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    myGrid.jqGrid('editRow',selRowId);
                    $('#voucherGrid_ilsave').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $('#voucherGrid_ilcancel').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                    $('#voucherGrid_iladd').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                }
            }
        },    
        add: true,edit: false, save: true,  cancel: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    });
```

What is wrong on my code?